# C# Exception Handling: Get elements of extended CustomException

Tags: c#, exception

I want to catch custom exceptions and return a custom object containing information about the exception. For this I have created a custom *CustomInvalidException* that extends *Extension*:

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomInvalidException<T> : Exception
    where T : Entity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; set; }

    public CustomInvalidException(string message)
        : base($"{typeof(T).Name}: {message}")
    {
        this.Title = "Custom invalid exception";
        this.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
    }
}
```

At some point I can throw this exception:

```
if (something) throw new CustomInvalidException<CustomEntity>(message);
```

And I can catch this exception and handle it in some middleware I use for this:

```
private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
{
    // Here I want to create a response with error information
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)exception.StatusCode;

    var result = new {exception.Title, exception.StatusCode, exception.Message}

    return context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
}
```

This gives errors since I try to get *exception.Title* and *exception.StatusCode*, and these elements do not exist on the *Exception* class. In debug mode I can see that these elements are present since I thrown the *CustomInvalidException*.

I want to keep the HandleExceptionAsync method as generic as possible, but I can only get these values by explicitly casting to *CustomInvalidException* (which is not what I want). How can I achieve the result as generic as possible?

**EDIT**

*HandleExceptionAsync* is called in the *ErrorHandlingMiddleware* class:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
     // Handle exception
    }
}
```

Which in turn is called in the Configure of Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));
```

Comment: I want A, but it cannot.  How would you read `exception.Title` from an exception that doesn't implement the Title property. Either change the parameter to CustomInvalidException. or decide what you want to return when it isn't a `CustomInvalidException`

Comment: Show the place where and how HandleExceptionAsync is called

Comment: Generics is just one possibility, but there are others: reflection, interfaces, using certain patterns to query missing info (e.g. a dictionary with exception as key).